# ERROR - ANDROID SDK path is not set

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10

I am trying to use an Android app in the new BB10 and I have to create the BAR file from the APK. I am having an issue when trying to run apk2bar from eclipse. It always says:

> [ERROR] Android SDK path is not set

As I have been investigating there should be a fix creating a system variable ANDROID_HOME with the path, but when I do, apk2bar returns this different error:

> [ERROR] Invalid %ANDROID_HOME% path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

I found some answers that says it gets solved when the path has no spaces but I tried it and got the same error:

> [ERROR] Invalid %ANDROID_HOME% path: C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? How can I execute this and what to change to fix it?

Thanks in advance!!!

PS: I am going to try with the ADT v21 instead of 22. I will tell...

SOLVED!! All this problems came after switching for a new computer. When I installed Android SDK, I did not install Android 2.3.3. I just did install 4.0.3. So also install 2.3.3.

If anyone has a related problem just comment and I will answer. Thanks!!

Comment: I suggest to move the SDK in a folder which doesn't have spaces

Comment: thanks system32, I tried it but [ERROR] Invalid %ANDROID_HOME% path: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution at the website at the blackberry supportforum.Hoping it helpful :-)

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/repackaging-android-code-apk-quot-android-sdk-path-is-not-set/td-p/2369697

Comment: Hello, I already did it; installed again but the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry I did not accept the answer before, is clear it is part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution provided here. Please try and let me know.
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Any-real-BB-moderators-ACTUALLY-on-these-forums/td-p/2375327

It worked for me. The issue for me was upgrading to ADT v22

> As a temporary solution, you can copy all of the files from
>   /build-tools/17.0.0 back to /platform-tools.
>   This will allow our tools (apk2barVerfifier, apk2bar, etc.) to
>   function as expected. You may need to provide the SDK location
>   directly to the tool, depending how you've got things setup.